# SQL- Find course where each student is best at

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have three following tables:

| Student | Home_assignments | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Student_id | Code |
| Firstname | Course_code | Teacher |
| Lastname | Date | Course_name |
|  | Task_nr |  |
|  | Filename |  |
|  | Points |  |
|  | Task_id |  |

Task is pretty simple:

> Using tables student, course and home_assignments find course for each
> student where he/she is the best using average points of each
> student's home_assignments points.

Desired output should look something like this:

| Firstname | Course_name | average_best |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Oracle:Sql | 10 |
| Bob | Math | 8 |
| Will | Economics | 10 |
| Mary | Math | 5 |

So far, what I have tried is I got the average points of courses where student is in:

```
SELECT s.lastname, s.firstname, avg(h.points) AS average_best, c.course_name
FROM course c,
     home_assignments h,
     student s
WHERE c.code = h.course_code AND h.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY c.course_name, s.lastname, s.firstname;
```

And also almost desired output, but it doesn't display `course_name`. But showing me firstname, lastname and student average for the course he/she is best at

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, max(average_best) AS the_best 
FROM 
     (
     SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, avg(h.points) AS average_best, c.course_name 
     FROM course c, 
          home_assignments h, 
          student s 
     WHERE c.code=h.course_code and h.student_id=s.id 
     GROUP BY c.course_name, s.lastname, s.firstname
     ) 
GROUP BY firstname, lastname;
```

Now, what is the possible way to select the course where each student is the best at?

Comment: Aren't you taught to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax?!? In 2022... Scary.

Comment: You need something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student.Id ORDER BY average_best DESC)`  to get what you want, or some subqueries. I appreciate the effort you put into the question, but it will help to provide a reproducible example using e.g. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). And what @jarlh says. I can't fathom you are learning that SQL syntax. Please look into more modern ways to joining tables. (`cource c INNER JOIN home_assignments h ON c.code = h.cource_code`)

Comment: What RDBMS... Cross apply / lateral may work as it is a table value function which allows you to "Order a subquery results" and return the "TOP X or limit X related to a value in an outer table.  Though a having clause will likely get you there just as easily.  GROUP BY X Having AVG = MAX(h.points) since the group by is already by subject.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, you may want to state that and any limitations that should be applied.  It may help answerers provide better responses for that context and avoid getting you into trouble based on your instructor's definition of cheating.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions